# Using VBA I need to identify multiple merged fields in a worksheet and then apply a formula to the left of each of those merged fields

Tags: excel, vba

Alright Team, I am hurting here.  I have a sheet with 30K row where the name of the call agent is merged between B and M lets say at rows 20 then 45,61,72 so on and so on.  I am looking to identify those merged rows in this sheet and then apply a formula in cell A immediately next to the merged cells - the formula reads `=RIGHT(Bxx,SEARCH(" ",Bxx,1)-1)` (which brings back the agent numbers I need).  Lastly I want to carry this agent number down for each cell in column A until it reaches the next agent number.  So the result of `=RIGHT(B20,SEARCH(" ",B20,1)-1)` would carry until it reached the new result for `=RIGHT(B45,SEARCH(" ",B45,1)-1)`.

So far I have only gotten to this point...and it clearly does not work. Any help is greatly apprecaited.

```
Sub FindMergedFields() 'finds and unmerges merged cells
    Dim rng As Range
    Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "B"), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "M")).Select
    For Each rng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If rng.MergeCells Then
            'rng.UnMerge
           ' rng.Formula = Right(B, Search(" ", B, 1) - 1)
            Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Formula = Right(Right(B, Search(" ", B, 1) - 1))
            'Range("h2").Formula = "=IF(B8="""","""",VLOOKUP(B8,'sheet2'!C4:D200,2,FALSE))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You should format the code properly in order to make your question more clear

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what the formula is trying to do, but you can put a formula into Column A as follows:

```
Sub FindMergedFields()
    Dim x As Long, FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    FirstRow = 2 ' Change this to your first data row. I'm assuming Row 1 contains headings and data starts with Row 2.
    ' Finds last row based on contents of Column A (assuming Column A is always populated). Change this if needed.
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For x = FirstRow To LastRow
        If Cells(x, 2).MergeCells Then ' Check column B of each row
            Range(Cells(x, "B"), Cells(x, "M")).UnMerge
            Cells(x, 1).Formula = "=RIGHT(B" & x & ",SEARCH("" "",B" & x & ",1)-1)" ' Place formula in Column A
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

As you can see, you don't need to go through all the cells in the used range for columns B-M: just check column B for each one. If it's part of any merged range, it will trigger the "If" clause.

I tried it and it works for me, when B-M are merged. Adjust the formula to suit your purpose.